# LVM2 Extend Issue

Tags: linux, lvm

I've done LVM resizes numerous times, but I can't seem to figure this problem out. ext3 filesystem, extra space is available on the VG, but the `lvextend` command continually fails:

```
lvextend -v -L+50G /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol05
    Finding volume group VolGroup00
    Archiving volume group "VolGroup00" metadata (seqno 7).
  Extending logical volume LogVol05 to 100.00 GB
    Creating volume group backup "/etc/lvm/backup/VolGroup00" (seqno 8).
    Found volume group "VolGroup00"
    Found volume group "VolGroup00"
    Clearing inactive table VolGroup00-LogVol05 (253:4)
    Loading VolGroup00-LogVol05 table
  /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol05: matchpathcon 0120000 failed: No such file or directory
  Failed to create symlinks for LogVol05.
  Failed to suspend LogVol05
```

The only thing I can find out about the matchpathcon binary is that it's related to SELinux, which is currently disabled on the server.

A little info on the VG:

```
  LV       VG         Attr   LSize  Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  LogVol00 VolGroup00 -wi-ao 48.83G                                      
  LogVol01 VolGroup00 -wi-ao  8.00G                                      
  LogVol02 VolGroup00 -wi-ao 48.83G                                      
  LogVol03 VolGroup00 -wi-ao 48.83G                                      
  LogVol04 VolGroup00 -wi-ao 48.83G                                      
  LogVol05 VolGroup00 -wi-ao 50.00G
```

Comment: Do you have any snapshots of this LV? Edit: NM looks like you don't.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695374) or something very similar. Please try to install selinux-policy-targeted package. SELinux is disabled but it looks like that LVM needs some files from this package.